# Swift 3: Different kind of elements in an array are not acceptable

Tags: arrays, swift3

Up until Swift 2.2 I was able to do this:

```
for each in [myUIButton,myUILabel] {
 each.hidden = true
}
```

but in Swift 3 this is not acceptable because label, button etc are not the same kind of element. I have already changed line 2 to **each.isHidden = true**

It throws "**Heterogeneous collection literal...**" error. When you fix it by adding [Any], it throws "**Cast 'Any' to 'AnyObject..**" error.

Is there an easy fix to this problem?

Comment: What's the type of `myButton`, `myLabel`, `x`, `y` and `z`? If they all inherit from `UIView`, then the compiler should be able to infer the array as `[UIView]`. In any case, a self-contained example would be extremely helpful.

Comment: edited question for clarification and typo

Comment: That's still not a self-contained example – this is: `let a = UIView(); let b = UIButton(); for view in [a, b] {view.isHidden = true}`, and it compiles just fine.

Comment: I dare say your problem is that you're using `hidden` as opposed to `isHidden`. Otherwise, your example compiles just fine using Swift3 and Xcode 8 assuming myUIButton is of type `UIButton` and myUILabel is of type `UILabel.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a common ancestor class having `isHidden` property, and explicitly cast to it:

```
for each in [myUIButton, myUILabel] as [UIView] {
    each.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for understanding the question. Some seem to be denouncing the question without understanding it.

Comment: under the hood what is different in Swift 3 vs Swift 2 which generates such an issue?

Comment: @Honey, generally, Swift 3 is not good at inferring collection types, and tend to make `[Any]` for arrays, with which we cannot apply any methods.

Answer (score 1):

All items in your array must have a common subclass, like `UIView` in the case of myButton and myLabel (presumably) in order for type inference to take place.

```
let label = UILabel()
let button = UIButton()
let collectionView = UICollectionView()
let tableView = UITableView()

let array = [label, button, collectionView, tableView] // Type: [UIView]

for item in array {
    item.isHidden = true
}
```

This code will work for your purposes.

Furthermore, if they all conform to the same protocol, you must explicitly name the protocol they conform to.

```
protocol Commonality { 
    func commonMethod() { ... }
}

class ThingA: Commonality { ... } // Correctly conform to Commonality
class ThingB: Commonality { ... } // Correctly conform to Commonality
class ThingC: Commonality { ... } // Correctly conform to Commonality

let array: [Commonality] = [ThingA(), ThingB(), ThingC()]

for item in array {
    item.commonMethod()
}
```

This should work as well, but you must explicitly name the common protocol. Otherwise (at least in my tests), it downcasts everything down to `Any`.

Answer (score 0):

Tell Swift it's an `[Any]` array:

```
for each in [myButton,myLabel,x,y,z] as [Any] {
    each.hideen = true
}
```

But then you will get an error cause `Any` doesn't have a property called `hideen` (typo?).

Comment: I already tried this. It gives further errors. (edited question for clarification and typo. )

Comment: Just use `as [UIView]`, which does have `isHidden`